# Azure AD Device Registered Column

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I cannot find any way to export the registered date from AAD using any Powershell commandlets.

Comment: The cmdlet which might have the info is `Get-AzureADUserRegisteredDevice `.  Try to run the cmdlet and pipe into `Select-Object -First 1 | Format-List`.  This will take the first device and show you all of the available properties for it.  One of them might be the registered date.  If you find it, you can select that property by runnging `Get-AzureADUserRegisteredDevice  | select-Object -Property Property1,Propert2` etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned that it is not possible to do this within powershell currently.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Get-AzureADDevice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureaddevice?view=azureadps-2.0) and [Export-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-7) to export the registered device date from AAD.

An example for your reference:

```
Get-AzureADDevice -All $true | Export-Csv D:\Temp\AzureADDevice.csv
```

If you want to list devices registered by a user, you should use `Get-AzureADUserRegisteredDevice`.